# How to use MySQL's STR_TO_DATE in C++?

Tags: c++, mysql

I have the following MySQL insertion query in my C++ code:

```
snprintf(buffer, QUERY_MAX,
    "INSERT INTO players (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, PHONE_NUMBER, MONEY,  \
    USERNAME, PASSWORD, GENDER, INCOME_LEVEL, CRIME_LEVEL, DOB) \
    VALUES (\'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', %f, \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\',   \
    STR_TO_DATE(\'%s\', '%m/%d/%Y')             \
);", /* values */, "10/15/2017");
```

I get the following warnings:

> warning C4476: 'snprintf' : unknown type field character 'm' in format
>   specifier
>
> warning C4473: 'snprintf' : not enough arguments passed for format
>   string

It doesn't seem to like my format specifiers for STR_TO_DATE. It seems to be confusing MySQL format specifiers with C++'s. How can I fix this?

My date variable being passed to %s is my own format of '10/15/2017'.

In buffer, it has the following while debugging:

```
STR_TO_DATE('10/15/2017', 'm/-858993460/Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix C and MySQL formats. Use C format specifiers and pass parameters as string values:

```
STR_TO_DATE(\'%s\', '%s/%s/%s')
```

Also, you are doing this wrong as this is SQL injection prone code. Use prepared statements with parameters instead.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the percentages in the MySQL part of the format string by using `%%`.

```
STR_TO_DATE(\'%s\', '%%m/%%d/%%Y')
```